# VBScript: 2 Problems in Script that changes Visio Key

Tags: vbscript, registry, ms-office

**What I want to do with my script:**

1. Check in registry, if Visio is installed
2. If yes: Change the key to the stated visio key

I want to run this script in a group policy (machine) which is run on startup.

**What is not working?**

1. The script returns always 'not existent' even if the key exists
2. If I run only the ospp.vbs part of the script (which should write the Visio key), it doesnt change anything.

It doesn't matter, if I run this script over GPO or directly as administrator on the client.
Sooooo... here's the script:

```
Option explicit
Dim sKey, bFound, objShell
skey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VAL_3.7\MSVisioProf2010_ENG"

with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On error resume next   
    sValue = .regread(sKey)       ' read attempt
    bFound = (err.number = 0)     ' test for success
  on error goto 0                 ' restore error trapping
end with

if bFound then
  wsh.echo "Found:", sValue
  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
  objShell.run "cscript " & Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OSPP.vbs" & Chr(34) & "/inpkey:7MCW8-VRQVK-G677T-PDJCM-Q8TCP"

 else
  wsh.echo "Not found"
end if

Set objShell = Nothing
```